# Hide Checkbox Column in MUI X DataGrid while printing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I have an MUI X DataGrid with some columns including checkbox column, when I print the table, the checkbox column will also be printed. Is there any way to hide it only when the user wants to print the table?

Screenshot of the table in printing mode:
https://ibb.co/dQydCNj

I tried hiding the checkbox, but it also hid it in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can can hide these checkboxes with CSS.

Here you can access the CSS classnames used by data-grid.
https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#css

You also can inspect the webpage and find that it uses "***.MuiCheckbox-root***" classname to wrap checkboxes.
You can apply ***"displayPrint: "none"*** property to hide checkboxes when printing the page.

```
      <DataGrid
        ...
        sx={{ 
          ".MuiCheckbox-root": {
            displayPrint: "none",
          },
        }}
      />
```